# emulating rejected call android-eclipse indigo

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-indigo

My app makes a call to a saved number, this number is bound to reject the call. How can i simulate the rejected outgoing call in the emulator? I am using eclipse indigo IDE.  All the actions are completely program driven. There are processes which have to be run once the call is rejected.

Comment: Emulator can not create/make call.

Comment: the app makes the call, the emulator needs to simulate that the call was rejected by the user instead of the usual acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 emulators, dial the port number of one of them (i.e. 5556), the reject the call in this emulator and it will be endend on the emulator placing the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DDMS perspective for achieving this.
Goto DDMS -> Emulator control -> Enter the incoming number you have already saved in the emulator and make a call.

```
public class PhoneStateListenerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    PhoneStateListener listener;
    TelephonyManager manager;

    manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    listener = new PhoneStateListener(){
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            String stateString = "N/A";
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
              stateString = "Idle";
              break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
              stateString = "Off Hook";
              break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              stateString = "Ringing";
              break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(PhoneStateListenerActivity.this, stateString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }           
    };

    manager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

}

Comment: that's for simulating an incoming call. I need a way that simulates the rejection of an outgoing call.

Comment: You mean the animation which occurs during rejection of a call ?

Comment: I am not bothered about the animation. My purpose is to do processes post rejection of the call I make from my app. I need the emulator to reject the call so that i can identify that the call was rejected and my processes can begin.

Comment: PhoneStateListener interface can help you solve your problem. Use the onCallStateChanged.

Comment: thank you, but this should help me once i'm done figuring out my question. my query is regarding the emulator not the app.